# How do I view surface in ParaView?

Tags: paraview

I created a collection of particles that are held together by a bond. The file is in `.vtu` format. I don't get to see the particles when I tried to view the surface: only the collections of the bonds were shown.

This is what I am getting:

[image]

Comment: Is this a programming question? I wonder if _Super User_ would be better here?

Comment: Probably the particles are represented as the "points" in the unstructured grid. There are numerous ways to show the points of a grid. One way is to change the representation from "Surface" to "Point Gaussian". Does that show the particles?

Comment: @halfer: paraview is a used tag word in stack overflow, not in super user.